# How to store multiple stream socket resources in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, sockets

I have a TCP server created using `stream_socket_server()`. Then I have an endless loop calling `stream_socket_accept()`. So far this is working and accepts as many connections as I throw at it. However if I try to store the accepted connections, in an array for example, the `stream_socket_accept()` function stops accepting further connection. This only happens if I add the stream resources to the array(). Here is an example:

```
<?php
$errcode = $errmsg = null;
$sock = stream_socket_server('tcp://0.0.0.0:65000', $errcode, $errmsg, STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN);
if ($sock === false) {
    stream_set_blocking($sock, 0);
}

$storage = array();
for (;;) {
    $con = @stream_socket_accept($sock, 0);

    if ($con !== false) {
        echo "Connection received\n";
        $storage[] = $con;//After this line, some of the next stream_socket_accept will not accept further connections
        $con = @stream_socket_accept($sock, 0);
    }
    usleep(20000);
}
```

You can test the script by opening a lot of connections like this(in bash/zsh/whatever):

```
for a in {1..100}; do telnet localhost 65000 &; done
```

What is even weirder is that if I try to open 100 connections, from the browser, only one will be accepted:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:65000", "echo");
}
```

To test this, save the JavaScript above as a snippet in Google Chrome and run it. Note that if the connection is not added to the `$storage` array, the JavaScript code will also get all of its 100 connection attempts accepted, thanks!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would start with removing all `@` before function calls so if there's an error you'll actually learn about that. Also, make sure you have error reporting enabled and set to report all errors.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the accepted connection resources, *when not stored*, are automatically closed and freed after no longer being referenced due to a new `stream_socket_accept()` assigned to the same resource variable, so that there are not a hundred connections at the same time. Your setup just doesn't support that many.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have another `stream_socket_accept` on line 15, you should only have one.

You may also add a timeout, such as `1` (second) instead of your `0`, and remove `@` as it's bad practice (you may have a big issue, and never know about it): `$con = stream_socket_accept($sock, 1);`.

Comment: I am sorry I have totally forgotten about this question here. As far as I remember it turned out to only be an issue with HHVM on MacOS, so technically this is not even a PHP issue. Title is wrong, I don't know why I wrote it that way. I have not used HHVM for a long time though, so this may not even be an issue anymore. As for the `@` sign, it was because of some warning that HHVM was spitting. Adding a timeout of 1 second was not an option, because this piece of code was part of an async loop, so potentially sleeping for a second was not acceptable.

Comment: So it would be a double `while` :-) Async loop... with no possible exit in your loop? But perhaps it wasn't the whole code, so there's no reason to talk about it anymore :-)